# Woking up lately for sahur

Tags: halal-haram

Salam aleykum warahmotullah.
I woke up lately today for sahur here normally sahur ends around 5:25am and I woke up by 5:40 and I rushed to drink water Is my fasting still valid,
Note:my alarm do woke at 3:00am after I stopped the alarm unfortunately I slept off till 5:40

Comment: Fasting started when Sahur ended. It doesn’t matter if you overslept or not, you missed the opportunity to eat and drink.

Comment: At what time is fajr?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I'm assuming 5:25 since OP states that's when sahur ends.

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile well I know from the Turkish that suhur ends 10 minutes or more before fajr. Beside the fact that Turkish mosques follow their own calculations.

Comment: @Medi1Saif interesting to know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

W/salam
Please note that such kind of fast is not valid... You have to make it again after Ramadan.